# Thunderbird add-on for scheduled sending

Tags: thunderbird

I am searching for a Mozilla Thunderbird add-on with the following requirements:

- **Purpose**: Delays sending of an e-mail until the next 12:00-13:00 block.
- **Criteria**:

  - **Automatic**: Clicking "Send" in Thunderbird does this automatically without asking for more information (as opposed to the [Send Later](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/) add-on)
  - **Maintained**: Available for Thunderbird version 50 and higher (as opposed to [BlunderDelay](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/blunderdelay/))